# Sort array with string dates Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have an  NSMutableArray of Strings. The Strings in the array, are converted from dates to Strings and I need to sort them and show them in a tableview.

I need:

June 24, 2011
June 26, 2011
July 1, 2011

And so on.

I know questions similar to this have been asked, but I didn´t get it to work. So I would really appreciate if someone could help me!

Answer (score 4):

Sort them while they're still dates, keep them as a sorted list of dates, and only format them as text as needed for display (i.e., during `-tableView:cellForIndexPath:`).

Alternatively, the ISO 8601 date formats (an example formatted date would be 20110603T1345.123-4) mostly sort lexicographically the same as they would as dates. Times in different time zones or that cross a summer time shift can invalidate this property, though, so leaving dates as dates would still be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this is to create a function of the form

```
NSInteger funcName(id left, id right, void* extra);
```

you can then use NSMutableArray's `sortUsingFunction:context:` passing your comparison function in.  Jeremy is correct in stating that dates are easier to sort, they have built in comparison functions:

```
– isEqualToDate:
– earlierDate:
– laterDate:
– compare:
```

See [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for sorting information and [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for its comparison methods

Answer (score 0):

Your `NSMuatbleArray` must have the `NSDate` object.

First you need to sort the array using  `-[NSMutableArray sortUsingSelector:]`  and need to pass **@selector(compare:)**.

The `compare:` function of `NSDate` will do the job for you and sort the array in ascending order ..

After following the above you just need to call `reloadData` function of `UITableView`.

Comment: Do you mean:
[myMutableArray addObject:date];
[myMutableArray sortUsingSelector:(compare:)];
?